# How can I convert a geoshape/geotrace/geopoint to GeoJSON?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, odk, kobotoolbox

I Am using API to access spatial data collected using kobotoolbox. the api returns spatial data either as geoshape/geotrace/geopoint, but I need to covert that data to Geojson so that I can display them on my map using leaflet.

here is sample string  of geoshape `'-6.725577650887138 39.10606026649475 0.0 0.0;-6.72631550943841 39.10506717860699 0.0 0.0;-6.727484560110362 39.10561669617891 0.0 0.0;-6.727484560110362 39.10561669617891 0.0 0.0;-6.725577650887138 39.10606026649475 0.0 0.0;'`

thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "geoshape" doesn't look like any [well-known vector data format](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html) but rather looks like a string of `;`-separated 4-element vectors, which in turn are space-separated numbers.

Some naïve parsing is in order.

Start by splitting the string into an array of strings [with `String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
let geoshape = '-6.725577650887138 39.10606026649475 0.0 0.0;-6.72631550943841 39.10506717860699 0.0 0.0;-6.727484560110362 39.10561669617891 0.0 0.0;-6.727484560110362 39.10561669617891 0.0 0.0;-6.725577650887138 39.10606026649475 0.0 0.0;';

let points = geoshape.split(';');
```

Now `points` is an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of `String`s. We can turn each of those strings into an `Array` of `Number`s by providing a function that splits it by spaces:

```
function spaceSeparatedStringToArray(str) {
     return str.split(' ');
}
```

...and another function that coerces a `String` containing the textual representation of a number into a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), like...

```
function stringToNumber(str) {
    return Number(str);
}
```

...and now let's put in [some `Array.prototype.map()` magic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and some [method chaining magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), to make a function in which the input is a space-separated string and the output is an `Array` of `Number`s:

```
function stringToNumber(str) { return Number(str); }

function spaceSeparatedStringToArrayOfNumbers(str) {
    return str.split(' ').map(stringToNumber);
}
```

Sometimes it's nicer to define those auxiliary functions passed to `map()` (or `reduce()` or `filter()` or etc) as [anonymous lambda-functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function), like:

```
function spaceSeparatedStringToArrayOfNumbers(str) {
    return str.split(' ').map(function(str){ return Number(str) });
}
```

You can use [arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead if you want:

```
function spaceSeparatedStringToArrayOfNumbers(str) {
    return str.split(' ').map(str=>Number(str) );
}
```

And since we're using [`Number` as a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#function_syntax), we can directly use that as the parameter of `map()`:

```
function spaceSeparatedStringToArrayOfNumbers(str) {
    return str.split(' ').map(Number);
}
```

Now that we have that function, let's go back to the beginning, and apply that function to each of the `;`-separated substrings:

```
function spaceSeparatedStringToArrayOfNumbers(str) {
    return str.split(' ').map(Number);
}

let geoshape = '-6.725577650887138 39.10606026649475 0.0 0.0;-6.72631550943841 39.10506717860699 0.0 0.0;-6.727484560110362 39.10561669617891 0.0 0.0;-6.727484560110362 39.10561669617891 0.0 0.0;-6.725577650887138 39.10606026649475 0.0 0.0;';

let points = geoshape.split(';');

let vectors = points.map(spaceSeparatedStringToArrayOfNumbers);
```

Let's change that to add even more lambda and method chaining and arrow syntax:

```
let vectors = geoshape.split(';').map((str)=>str.split(' ').map(Number));
```

Also, since the GeoJSON format expects each coordinate as a 2-component vector instead of a 4-component vector, let's `map` each vector again to keep only the first two components. This uses [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
let vectors = geoshape
               .split(';')
               .map((str)=>str.split(' ').map(Number))
               .map(([x,y,w,z])=>[x,y]);
```

See? I defined a lambda-function that takes a single argument, assumes it's an array (of numbers) with length 4, destructures the array, then returns a new array containing the first two elements. It can also work like:

```
let coords = geoshape
               .split(';')
               .map((str)=>str.split(' ').map(Number))
               .map(([x,y])=>[x,y]);
```

Your sample data ends with a `;`, and that causes an empty string, so I'll filter that out as well:

```
let coords = geoshape
               .split(';')
               .filter(str=> str!=='')
               .map((str)=>str.split(' ').map(Number))
               .map(([x,y])=>[x,y]);
```

I'm gonna assume that you're working in Dar es-Salaam and not in Badajoz, so let's flip latitude and longitude (see https://macwright.com/lonlat/ as well) by swapping `x` and `y` in `([x,y])=>[y,x]`:

```
let coords = geoshape
               .split(';')
               .filter(str=> str!=='')
               .map((str)=>str.split(' ').map(Number))
               .map(([x,y])=>[y,x]);
```

Now head over to [geojson.org](https://geojson.org/) and read [RFC 7946](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946) to see how GeoJSON data structures are specified. We already have the coordinates of a LineString geometry, so all it needs is some wrapping:

```
let geojsonFeature = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": coords
  }
};
```

If your sample dataset is meant to be a polygon with an outer hull and no inner hulls (read [OGC SFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Features) to know what "hull" means in this context), then you can wrap the coordinates in an extra inline array and specify `Polygon` as the geometry type:

```
let geojsonFeature = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [ coords ]
  }
};
```

Now you can feed it to `L.geoJson`, e.g.

```
let line = L.geoJson(geojsonFeature).addTo(map);
```

And finally, I'm gonna compact everything together just for the sake of it:

```
let geoshape = '-6.725577650887138 39.10606026649475 0.0 0.0;-6.72631550943841 39.10506717860699 0.0 0.0;-6.727484560110362 39.10561669617891 0.0 0.0;-6.727484560110362 39.10561669617891 0.0 0.0;-6.725577650887138 39.10606026649475 0.0 0.0;';

let leafletLine = L.geoJson({
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": geoshape
                   .split(';')
                   .filter(str=> str!=='')
                   .map((str)=>str.split(' ').map(Number))
                   .map(([x,y])=>[y,x])
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

See a [working example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/1parXFURMrro0PgP). And please, **please**, don't copy-paste code blindly. Do read the linked documentation and resources, and understand what's going on.